# How to get score on elasticsearch query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

**Update**

I changed "filter" to "must" and got scoring! Not sure how I missed this.

---

I'm struggling to figure out why my boolean query isn't resulting in any scores! Every hit has score 0.

```py
    result = es.search(
        index="tweets",
        size="50",
        body={
            "_source": [
                "text",
                "author_id",
                "created_at",
                "polarity_scores",
                "public_metrics",
            ],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {"query_string": {"query": search_query}},
                        {"range": {"created_at": {"gte": recently}}},
                    ]
                }
            },
        },
    )
```

I'm new to elasticsearch and using it in a Search Engine course, so I was hoping to be able to focus on score boosting rather than getting scores to show up at all... Happy for any tips, hints etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every hit has a score of 0 because you are using the `filter` clause**

As mentioned in the elasticsearch official documentation, in the [`filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause the score of the query is ignored

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike
> must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
> executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching.

If you want to get the score, use the `must` clause instead of the `filter` clause

The modified query will be

```
{
  "_source": [
    "text",
    "author_id",
    "created_at",
    "polarity_scores",
    "public_metrics",
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": search_query
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": recently
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised simultaneously as you wrote.